# Transfer Exception with InnerException from the server to the client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have error handler that convert Exception in FaultException and sends it on client.
Code:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    var exceptionDetail = new ExceptionDetail(error);
    var faultException = new FaultException<ExceptionDetail>(exceptionDetail, error.Message);
    MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
}
```

But in this case, services gets Exception without InnerException and InnerException may contain another InnerException.
Is it possible to pass an Exception occurs on the server to the client without conversion to FaultException or ensure the transfer with the FaultException of all InnerExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I am imagining that you want to get the `.NET Exception` that happens on the WebService/"server" packaged up/serialized into a `FaultException`, and then when received by the "client" it's unpacked and raised as the original regular `.NET Exception`....rather than as just a `FaultException` - this is called "Exception Marshalling".

This is sometimes needed when you aren't able to modify the client code to add the `FaultException` handling, or you don't want the client code to be polluted with "webservice" specific knowledge i.e. your code just deals with .NET Exceptions.

(Note: this is bypassing "Exception Shielding"...which is frowned upon a bit as you may expose details in the exception data transferred to the client which might allow attack vectors...plus it may make your "webservice" less interoperable...i.e. non .NET clients would need to know how to understand the serialized .NET Exception information).

### On the Server

So on the "server" you had the right idea on adding a behaviour to your service that implements `IErrorHandler`.

But you should try "serializing" the `Exception` but fall back to the `Exception.Message` if it cannot be done.

There are a few different implementations of `ProvideFault` that do this...pick the one you like best.

- http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/
- https://code.google.com/p/ppwcode/source/browse/dotnet/Vernacular/Persistence/trunk/I/Dao/Wcf/Helpers/Errors/ExceptionMarshallingErrorHandler.cs?r=5303
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f15a5edf-b3ff-43e6-be90-b943141a286e/throwing-exception-from-wcf-service-client-not-receiving-same-error-message?forum=wcf

The "ppwcode" one is the best as it reconstructs the stack trace, and recurses the chain to record the `InnerExceptions`. It's not exactly correct though as it only checks the Serializable attribute on the "root" exception....so if any of the `InnerExceptions` were not serializable, then it wouldn't work.

This is what I ended up using to package up the Exception on the server:

```
void IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    if (error is FaultException)
    {
        // Let WCF do normal processing
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // This takes an exception, and tries to serialize it, so
            // that it can be encoded into a <soap:Fault> <soap:Detail>
            // element. The client, can then deserialize the detail to
            // rebuild the exception information.
            //
            // Not all exceptions are serializable! Thus if our
            // serialization fails, then we will instead return a
            // general exception whose content will be string
            // representatiion of the exception.
            MessageFault messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(
                new FaultCode("ExceptionMarshallingErrorHandlerV1"),
                new FaultReason(error.Message),
                error,
                new NetDataContractSerializer());
            if (messageFault != null)
            {
                fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                // This isn't strictly correct, as the "stack trace" information
                // is lost, and the InnerExceptions too....but I didn't think them
                // important at the time...and anyway all the exceptions I expected
                // were serializable, so this shouldn't have been hit.
                //
                // This is effectively a different way to create the MessageFault
                // compared to yours.
                //
                // If you look at the "ppwcode" code, then it tries to
                // handle the non-serializable exceptions in a better way...by
                // recording the stack trace and InnerExceptions.
                //
                // So I would suggest using:
                //
                // Exception ex = HandleNonSerializableException(error);

                Exception ex = new Exception(error.ToString());

                MessageFault messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(
                    new FaultCode("ExceptionMarshallingErrorHandlerV1"),
                    new FaultReason(error.Message),
                    ex,
                    new NetDataContractSerializer());
                if (messageFault != null)
                {
                    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, null);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Pass the "exception" back as a FaultException

                MessageFault messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(
                    new FaultCode("Exception (non-serializable)"),
                    new FaultReason(error.Message));
                if (messageFault != null)
                {
                    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, null);
                }

                fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From "ppwcode":

```
private static Exception HandleNonSerializableException(Exception e)
{
    string msg = e.Message;
    msg = string.Format(
        "Exception of type {1} wasn't serializable, rethrown as plain exception.{0}{0}Original message:{0}{2}{0}{0}Original Stacktrace:{0}{3}",
        Environment.NewLine,
        e.GetType().Name,
        msg,
        e.StackTrace);

    Exception inner = e.InnerException;
    while (inner != null)
    {
        msg = string.Format(
            "{1}{0}{0}InnerException:{0}{2}{0}{0}StackTrace:{0}{3}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            msg,
            inner.Message,
            inner.StackTrace);
        inner = inner.InnerException;
    }
    return new ProgrammingError(msg);
}
```

### On the Client

Now on the client you need to access the `FaultException` that is returned to it and unpackage the exception held inside it and raise it as a `.NET Exception`.

So you need something that "hooks" into the client side channel stack...and "inspects" the message reply that is received - `IClientMessageInspector` has a `AfterReceiveReply`....which gives you that opportunity.

There are several different ways to get the "inspector" applied to your client channel stack.

One way is to create a custom `Attribute` which you decorate your service contract with. This `Attribute` implements `IContractBehaviour` which has an `ApplyClientBehavior` which gives you an opportunity to specify your custom message inspector.

(you can also use this custom `Attribute` as a way to apply the custom `IErrorHandler` you want the webservice/"server" via the `ApplyDispatchBehavior`)

The "olegsych" link has a suitable "message inspector" to unpack the exception and a custom attribute called `ExceptionMarshallingBehavior` which you can use to apply it (it also has a `IErrorHandler` which can do the packing up for you too)....just apply it on the service contract.

So:

```
[ServiceContract(
    ......
    )
]
[ExceptionMarshallingBehavior]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(.....))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(.....))]
public interface IMyWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetVersion();

    ...
}
```

### For Reference

- http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/

Comment: Where there should be a method HandleNonSerializableExceptio()?
(question removed - found)

Comment: What is ProgrammingError?
My VisualStudio does not defined this class name

Comment: And one more thing: at the customer still comes FaultExcepton. How do I get there Exception?

Comment: I the google link looks outdated, i found ppwcode here: https://github.com/peopleware/net-ppwcode-vernacular-wcf/blob/a0a1282ccc691e3b8b170d931583aa08d556026e/src/I/ErrorHandlers/ExceptionMarshallingErrorHandler.cs